# Name being inserted, but file is not being uploaded

Tags: php, file-upload

I've an upload input field in a form. the problem that the name of the file is being inserted in the database but the file is not being uploaded to the server, and the same code is working on the same server in a different file in the same directory but in a different query. form is set to enctype="multipart/form-data",

here is the code where its not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php require_once("includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/dbc.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php confirm_logged_in(); ?>
<?php find_selected_post(); ?>

<?php
 $target = "../upload/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['post_photo']['name']); 

    if (intval($_GET['cat']) == 0) {
        redirect_to('cat_posts.php');
    }

    include_once("includes/form_functions.php");

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $errors = array();

        $required_fields = array('post_title', 'position', 'visible', 'post_content');
        $errors = array_merge($errors, check_required_fields($required_fields, $_POST));

        $fields_with_lengths = array('post_title' => 30);
        $errors = array_merge($errors, check_max_field_lengths($fields_with_lengths, $_POST));

        $category_id = mysql_prep($_GET['cat']);
        $post_title = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['post_title']));
        $post_content = mysql_prep($_POST['post_content']);
        $post_description = mysql_prep($_POST['post_description']);
        $post_keywords = mysql_prep($_POST['post_keywords']);
        $post_tags = mysql_prep($_POST['post_tags']);
        $post_photo =($_FILES['post_photo']['name']);
        $position = mysql_prep($_POST['position']);
        $visible = mysql_prep($_POST['visible']);



        if (empty($errors)) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO ss_posts (
                        post_title, post_content, post_description, post_keywords, post_tags, post_photo, position, visible, category_id
                    ) VALUES (
                        '{$post_title}',  '{$post_content}', '{$post_description}', '{$post_keywords}',  '{$post_tags}', '{$post_photo}', {$position}, {$visible}, {$category_id}
                    )";
            if ($result = mysql_query($query, $connection)) {
                $message = "Successfully Created.";
                $new_post_id = mysql_insert_id();
                redirect_to("cat_posts.php?post={$new_post_id}");
            } else {
                $message = "The Post Could Not Be Created.";
                $message .= "<br />" . mysql_error();
            }
        } else {
            if (count($errors) == 1) {
                $message = "There was 1 error in the form.";
            } else {
                $message = "There were " . count($errors) . " errors in the form.";
            }
        }
    }

?>
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<br/>target: " . $target;

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['post_photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    echo "<br/>Upload failed.";
} else {
    echo "<br/>Upload done.";
}
?>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>New Post - Administration Panel</title>
    <script src="js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/ckeditor/sample.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/button.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/hideshow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.equalHeight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
          $(".tablesorter").tablesorter(); 
     } 
    );
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //When page loads...
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });

    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('.column').equalHeight();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <header id="header">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="site_title"><a href="index.php">Administration Panel</a></h1>
            <h2 class="section_title">New Post</h2><div class="btn_view_site">
            <a href="../index.php">View Site</a></div>
        </hgroup>
    </header> 
    <!-- end of header bar -->

    <section id="secondary_bar">
        <div class="user">
            <p>Hello, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> (<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>)</p>
        </div>

        <div class="breadcrumbs_container">
            <article class="breadcrumbs"><a href="index.php">Administration Panel</a> 
            <div class="breadcrumb_divider"></div> 
            <a class="current">New Post</a></article>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- end of secondary bar -->

    <aside id="sidebar" class="column" style="height:160%;">

                <hr/>
        <h3>Pages</h3>
        <ul class="toggle">
            <li class="icn_new_article"><a href="new_page.php">Add a New Page</a></li>
            <li class="icn_edit_article"><a href="edit_page.php">Edit/Delete a Page</a></li>
        </ul>
                <hr/>

        <h3>Users</h3>
        <ul class="toggle">
            <li class="icn_add_user"><a href="add_user.php">Add New User</a></li>
            <li class="icn_view_users"><a href="view_users.php">View Users</a></li>
        </ul>
                <hr/>

        <h3>Blog</h3>
        <ul class="toggle">
            <li class="icn_categories"><a href="new_category.php">Create a Category</a></li>
            <li class="icn_new_article"><a href="cat_posts.php">Create/Edit a Post</a></li>
            <li class="icn_settings"><a href="blogwidgets.php">Home Blog Settings</a></li>
            <li class="icn_settings"><a href="blogsettings.php">Blog Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
                <hr/>
        <h3>Settings</h3>
        <ul class="toggle">
            <li class="icn_settings"><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
            <li class="icn_settings"><a href="logo.php">Site Logo</a></li>
            <li class="icn_jump_back"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>

        <footer>
                <hr />
            <p><strong>Copyright &copy; 2013 Sky Define</strong></p>
            <p>Powered by <a href="http://www.skydefine.com">Sky Define</a></p>
            </br>           
            </br>

        </footer>
    </aside><!-- end of sidebar -->

    <section id="main" class="column">

                            <?php


                                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['post_photo']['tmp_name'], $target);
            // output a list of the fields that had errors
            if (!empty($errors)) {
                echo "<p class=\"errors\">";
                echo "Please review the following fields:<br />";
                foreach($errors as $error) {
                    echo " - " . $error . "<br />";
                }
                echo "</p>";
            }
            ?>



        <article class="module width_full">
            <header><h3>New Post</h3></header>



        <div class="module_content">




            <h2>Adding New Post</h2>
            <?php if (!empty($message)) {echo "<p class=\"message\">" . $message . "</p>";} ?>
            <?php if (!empty($errors)) { display_errors($errors); } ?>

<div class="mws-panel grid_4">
                    <div class="mws-panel-header">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mws-panel-body">





            <form class="mws-form"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="new_post.php?cat=<?php echo $sel_category['id']; ?>" method="post">              
                                <div class="mws-form-inline">

                            <?php $new_post = true; ?>
            <?php if (!isset($new_post)) {$new_post = false;} ?>

                <div class="mws-form-row">
                                    <label>Post Name:</label>
                                    <div class="mws-form-item large">
                                        <input type="text" name="post_title" id="post_title"   class="mws-textinput" placeholder="Post Name Goes Here." />
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                <div class="mws-form-row">
                                    <label>Post Description:</label>
                                    <div class="mws-form-item large">
                                        <input type="text" name="post_description" id="post_description"  class="mws-textinput" placeholder="Post Description Goes Here." />
                                    </div>
                                </div>              

                                <div class="mws-form-row">
                                    <label>Post Keywords:</label>
                                    <div class="mws-form-item large">
                                        <input type="text" name="post_keywords" id="post_keywords"  class="mws-textinput"   placeholder="Post Keywords Goes Here, Separated By Commas!" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>



                <div class="mws-form-row">
                                    <label>Post Content:</label>
                                    <div class="mws-form-item large">
                                    <textarea name="post_content" id="post_content" class="ckeditor" > </textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                <div class="mws-form-row">
                                    <label>Post Tags:</label>
                                    <div class="mws-form-item large">
                                        <input type="text" name="post_tags" id="post_tags"  class="mws-textinput"   placeholder="Post Tags Goes Here, Separated By Commas!" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                    <div class="mws-form-row">
                                    <label>Edit Post Photo:</label>
                                    <div class="mws-form-item large">
                                        <input type="file"  name="post_photo"  id="post_photo" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                <div class="mws-form-row">
                                    <label>Position:</label>    
                             <div class="mws-form-item large">
                     <select name="position">
                    <?php
                    if (!$new_post) {
                        $post_set = get_posts_for_category($sel_post['category_id']);
                        $post_count = mysql_num_rows($post_set);
                    } else {
                        $post_set = get_posts_for_category($sel_category['id']);
                        $post_count = mysql_num_rows($post_set) + 1;
                        }
                    for ($count=1; $count <= $post_count; $count++) {
                    echo "<option value=\"{$count}\"";
                    if ($sel_post['position'] == $count) { echo " selected"; }
                    echo ">{$count}</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                    </select>   
                    </div>
                                </div>

                <div class="mws-form-row">
                                    <label>Visible:</label>
                                    <div class="mws-form-item large">

                    <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0"<?php 
                    if ($sel_post['visible'] == 0) { echo " checked"; } 
                    ?> /> No
                    &nbsp;
                    <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1"<?php 
                    if ($sel_post['visible'] == 1) { echo " checked"; } 
                    ?> /> Yes
                </div>
                            </div>








                                </form>




            <div class="mws-button-row">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Post" class="mws-button green" />
            <a class="mws-button red" href="index.php">Cancel</a>          

    </div>

                            </div>
                                </div>

            </div>

                </article>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </article><!-- end of stats article -->

        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </section>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection and arbitrary file upload.

Comment: You are using Wordpress?

Comment: no, im building a script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would try to find the error:

make your errors visible:

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
```

**$target** should be a **full path**.

Check your HTML form. Did you add the **enctype attribute**?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="script.php">
```

Is your **Input** correct?

```
<input type="file" name="post_photo"/>
```

What does the **$_FILES** array contents?

```
<?php echo print_r($_FILES); ?>
```

**Edit**

Please let us know the data these lines return:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<br/>target: " . $target;

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['post_photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    echo "<br/>Upload failed.";
} else {
    echo "<br/>Upload done."
}
?>
```

**Edit 2 (Solution)**:

Your submit-button is outside the form-Tag. That's why. Fix it like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Post" class="mws-button green" />
</form>
```

Comment: 1. not working when full path too
2. yes, i mentioned that in the questione.
3. the input is correct. i've a new post page and edit post page. its working fine on the edit post page but not on new post page.
4. what do you mean by the $_FILES array contents

Comment: @AhmadAbuAssab If the file was sent to your script, it will be in the $_FILES array. You should take a look at it's values by using print_r(). If it doesn't exist you can be sure, the error is before this line. Else the error is coming in the following lines. It's just to detect the errors location/line.

Comment: yes its being inserted in the database if you mean that, but not uploaded.

Comment: Take a look at my answer now and post what you get by the lines I added.

Comment: before i insert anything or submit i get this

 `
 Array
(
)

target: ../upload/
Upload failed.
 `

Comment: @AhmadAbuAssab check folder and file permissions

Comment: when i've made another error in the form like didn't put a required input, the upload went okay, but with everything correct. its not uploading

Comment: @AhmadAbuAssab: as you can see, your array is empty. That means, no data was sent. Please post your HTML code in your question.

Comment: i've posted it mr.bombastic

Comment: wow, that's messy! why do you've move_uploaded_file() two times?

Comment: Take a look at my second edit...

Comment: where ?!  i only see it once and once ! if not

Comment: use your search-function.

Comment: i did, i only see it once. and the form solution didnt work.

Comment: you've to add your attributes like method, action and enctype by your own. Just move your submit-buttom a few lines up.

Comment: i did move it up to get it inside the form tag. but its still the same

Comment: take a look at the code of your question. i changed it.

Comment: i did delete one of them. and i fixed the form already. still the same

Comment: okay i fixed it, thanks @Mr.Bombastic you really helped me much. i've another question that couldn't be fix if you have time. named ignoring blank fields

Answer (score 0):

Your `$target` should contain the root path

```
$target = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']"/upload/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['post_photo']['name']);
```

Comment: its not working as well

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: none, btw the name of the file is being inserted in the table, but not uploaded. but its working with an update query not insert. this is weird.

Comment: turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and put in `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['post_photo']['tmp_name'], $target))`